# InvalidCharacterError

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma variável `inputParams` com a string `"Teste StackOverflow€"`

Porém necessito fazer o `btoa()` dessa variável e está ocorrendo o erro:

> Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded
>   contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Eu preciso fazer o encode dessa string com o € para Base64, existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja essa [Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem), tem o encode e decode para base64 com caracteres unicode :

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
        function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}

b64EncodeUnicode('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
b64EncodeUnicode('\n'); // "Cg=="
```

Para Decode de volta a String utilize:

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}

b64DecodeUnicode('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
b64DecodeUnicode('Cg=='); // "\n"
```

Comment: Copie os exemplos pra cá, facilitará para as pessoas.

Answer (score 4):

O problema está nesse caractere '€'. Segundo w3schools esse método só aceita os caracteres "AZ", "az", "0-9", "+", "/" e "="

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp

Comment: Eu preciso desse caractere  '€'.

Comment: Segue um demo para a solução do seu problema:

https://jsfiddle.net/m7v2ejzm/

Comment: funcionou obrigado @Netinho Santos

Answer (score 4):

Tente isso abaixo. Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> lá em baixo para testar.

```js
function unicodeEscape(str) {
    var map = {
        '\n': '\\n',
        '\\': '\\\\',
        '\f': '\\f',
        '\t': '\\t',
    };
    return str.replace(/[\s\S]/g, function(ch) {
        if (map[ch]) return map[ch];
        var code = ch.charCodeAt();
        if (code >= 32 && code <= 126) return ch;
        var u = ch.charCodeAt().toString(16),
            t = u.length > 2;
        return '\\' + (t ? 'u' : 'x') + ('0000' + u).slice(t ? -4 : -2);
    });
}

function unicodeUnescape(str) {
    var map = {
        '\\n': '\n',
        '\\r': '\r',
        '\\\\': '\\',
        '\\f': '\f',
        '\\t': '\t',
    };
    var hexMap = "0123456789abcdef";
    return str.replace(/\\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/g, function(ch) {
        return String.fromCharCode(
                hexMap.indexOf(ch.charAt(2)) * 16 +
                hexMap.indexOf(ch.charAt(3))
        );
    }).replace(/\\u[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/g, function(ch) {
        return String.fromCharCode(
                hexMap.indexOf(ch.charAt(2)) * 4096 +
                hexMap.indexOf(ch.charAt(3)) * 256 +
                hexMap.indexOf(ch.charAt(4)) * 16 +
                hexMap.indexOf(ch.charAt(5))
        );
    }).replace(/\\n/g, "\n").replace(/\\f/g, "\f").replace(/\\n/g, "\f").replace(/\\t/g, "\t").replace(/\\r/g, "\r").replace(/\\\\/g, "\\\\");
}

var teste = "Teste StackOverflow€";
var escape = unicodeEscape(teste);
var codificado = btoa(escape);
var decodificado = atob(codificado);
var desescapado = unicodeUnescape(decodificado);

$("#original").html(teste);
$("#escape").html(escape);
$("#codificado").html(codificado);
$("#decodificado").html(decodificado);
$("#desescapado").html(desescapado);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Original: <span id="original"></span></p>
<p>Escape: <span id="escape"></span></p>
<p>Codificado: <span id="codificado"></span></p>
<p>Decodificado: <span id="decodificado"></span></p>
<p>Desescapado: <span id="desescapado"></span></p>
```